# What does insert(), delete(), select() and update() of the MyBatis SqlSession Interface return?

Tags: java, database, mybatis

From the API Doc of mybatis i can just see, that insert, delete, select and update has an int as the returntype. But there is no documentation about what the meaning of the returned integers is.

Does this has something to do with Success of the operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select()` doesn't return anything. The others return the number of affected rows.

Comment: The affected number of rows are returned only if the driver supports that function; Oracle doesn't.

Comment: @climmunk can you provide some documentation?